# What is the proper way to do type hints in __init__ method while reading values from file without any warnings in PyCharm?

Tags: python

Let's say I have code like this and want to do the type hints inside `__init__` functions for all attributes I create. PyCharm gives me a warning because in `__init__` I set self.b to None. If I removed self.b from `__init__` and created it with type hint inside `read` method I would instead get a warning that I am creating a new attribute outside `__init__` function.
I don't want to hint that self.b can be of any other type than Vector3D. Another solution I don't want is initializing self.b to Vector3D(0,0,0) because that feels like pointlessly creating new object. So what is the proper way to write this without warnings ?

```py
from some_module import Vector3D

class A:
  def __init__(self, filename: str):
    self.a: list[int] = []
    self.b: Vector3D = None

    self.read(filename)

  def read(self, name: str):
     with open(name, 'r') as file:
       self.a = eval(file.readline().strip())
       self.b = Vector3D(*eval(file.readline().strip()))
```

Comment: It needs to be `Optional[Vector3D]` to allow `None` as a value.

Comment: In this case I don't really want it to be Optional because it can only be None when creating it in `__init__` and should never be None after leaving `__init__`

Comment: I don't think that's supported. Type hinting applies to the variable as a whole, not specific paths through the code.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loading the file in `__init__` using a classmethod as an alternate constructor could work

```
from some_module import Vector3D

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: list[int], b: Vector3D):
        self.a: list[int] = a
        self.b: Vector3D = b

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, name: str):
        with open(name, 'r') as file:
            return cls(
                eval(file.readline().strip()),
                Vector3D(*eval(file.readline().strip()))
            )


obj = A.from_file(filename)
```

Comment: This looks good. Though what would be the preferred solution if I had like 20 attributes to initialize this way ? 20 parameters in `__init__`  would probably not be good. I guess 1 list, dict or tuple parameter in such case ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the attributes in the method, have it return the values.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, filename: str):
    a, b = self.read(filename)
    self.a: list[int] = a
    self.b: Vector3D = b

  def read(self, name: str):
     with open(name, 'r') as file:
        a: list[int] = eval(file.readline().strip())
        b: Vector3D = Vector3D(*eval(file.readline().strip()))
     return a, b
```